# How to interact with Github API in python (without api wrapper)?

Tags: python, api, github, github-api

I am beginner in programming and I am getting familiar with (restful) apis and my tasks are:
- Create a repository
- Modify 'homepage' and 'description' fields
- Create a file (commit)
- find tree sha list that tree
- Delete file
- Add collaborators

I am trying to use curl (and/or maybe I should use python request module). At first I wanted to check whether or not my personal token works, with the following:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token mytoken" https://api.github.com/user
```

and I got an error message: "invalid syntax".

That's why I can't solve the tasks. For example with:

```
curl -X POST  -H "Authorization: token  mytoken" URL -d '{"key1":"valu1, "key2", "value2"}'
```

(I am using jupyter notebook)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your token has 41 chars:
`curl -H "Authorization: token 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901" https://api.github.com/user`

I've checked it and it works perfectly. If still in trouble, regenerate it from the Github website.